# Cant Convert Lists that are within Lists into integers

Tags: python, list, nested, int, nested-lists

i am currently having problems with converting elements that are in list within lists.

Note: I am trying to avoid the first list within the list [0] because i dont want it to be an integer by deleting it.

```
import urllib.request

def readWordList(urlData):

    response = urllib.request.urlopen ("http://www.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/marks.txt")

    html = response.readline()
    data = []

    while len(html) != 0:
        line = html.decode('utf-8').split()
        data.append(line)
        html = response.readline()
    
        
del data[0]
return data

print (readWordList("http://www.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/marks.txt"))
```

here are a few images of my current situation

## 1 [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEyPO.png)

## 2 [data that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1du3R.png)

I got my lists within lists but the information is formed into strings and I want to change the elements into integers. How can I do this?

Comment: Post the relevant code here directly, as text.

Comment: sorry im new to this, I just posted it.

Comment: First of all, do you get the right output you want? Second, I see non integer numbers sometimes, you still want to convert everything to integers?

Answer (score 0):

Before you return data you could have something like, in python 2:

```
for index,element in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = map(int, element)
```

or

```
for index,element in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = [int(i) for i in element]
```

or in Python 3

```
for index,element in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = list(map(int, element))
```

So for example your code will become something like

```
import urllib.request

def readWordList(urlData):

    response = urllib.request.urlopen ("http://www.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/marks.txt")

    html = response.readline()
    data = []

    while len(html) != 0:
        line = html.decode('utf-8').split()
        data.append(line)
        html = response.readline()


    del data[0]
    for index,element in enumerate(data):
        data[index] = map(int, element)
    return data

print (readWordList("http://www.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/marks.txt"))
```